# Quick drawing tool

Tags: software-recommendation, design, vector-drawings

I'm in need of some vector drawings... Was rushed to install inkscape, as is the tool I use more often, but it is too bloated and heavy for the task at hand...

I was thinking in something like Fireworks, that let's you create bitmaps in a very vector-like workflow, or something like the old Flash editor that would blend shapes if they had the same color.

Do you know of any app simpler than inkscape or along the lines of those products description?

Comment: nothing beats inkscape. try it once. its easy.

Comment: I do use inkscape regularly. I mean something simplier and faster to work with.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a list of [Linux graphic vector editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aLinux_vector_graphics_editors) in wikipedia. From looking at the articles linked from there, it looks like **Inkscape**, **Karbon14**, **OpenOffice.org Draw** and possibly **Dia** are currently actively developed.

Other previously popular programs, like Sodipodi, SK1, Pencil and Xara Xtreme are no longer actively maintained.

Comment: [Pencil](www.pencil-animation.org) is in the repos and not in that list. Although it has too much rough edges, I don't know if some of  them are because of gtk3.

Comment: @tutuca: Pencil is a nice program, thank you for mentioning it. However, its last release was in 2008 so it goes in the list of "no longer actively maintained". Which doesn't mean it can't or shouldn't be used - one just need to realize that it may stop working/be removed from the repos in the next release of Ubuntu, for example...

Comment: Inkscape is my favorite. The linux environment is definitely not short of that.

Answer (score 7):

Try [Xara Xtreme](http://www.xaraxtreme.org/). It's listed in Synaptic as `xaralx` package

Answer (score 4):

Also `shutter` - which is a screenshot taking program - has a very simple and nice vector drawing tool.

Comment: I like to use shutter for quickly adding notes and annotations to screenshots.

Comment: Very interesting. The Shutter DrawingTool looks like just what I need except that it can't blend shapes and doesn't appear to work stand alone...

Comment: Yeah - may be it'll be right to ask Shutter Developers for a separate release of DrawingTool alone (with appropriate enchansments).

Answer (score 4):

if you want a quick tool use

1) [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/): just a clone of MS paint.

2) [LibreOffice Draw](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/draw/): very convenient.

3) [gnome-paint](http://code.google.com/p/gnome-paint/) drawing editor: Very very lightweight and useful.

4) kolor paint: another clone of MS paint.

5) [gnu paint](http://gpaint.sourceforge.net/): fast and easy.

You can install them just from software center.

Comment: I don't know about others - but kolourpaint is not a vector tool.

Comment: Yes, gnome-paint neither. Its about vector drawing tools! Don't understand that this answer made it to score 3.

Comment: I don't understand why you got 73 reputation from this answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the best drawing tool on linux today is [Krita](http://krita.org). It combines vector and raster layers (and more) on the same canvas.

LWN did a brief [review](http://lwn.net/Articles/464495/) recently.

Answer (score 0):

Skencil its very simple, try it.

Comment: Last release in 2005, but sounded nice.

Comment: SVG has not changed too much since 2005 :)

Comment: :( i love activately mantained guis